# Autoload.php missing in PHP project

Tags: php

I cloned a php project of someone from github, but now I am stuck at one point because he didn't upload the autoload.php file in his repo, and now without that only the frontend of the project is running.

I tried googled also but i didn't get a specific solution for that

Is there anyway I can run that project?

(https://github.com/GodfallentheCelestial/Data-Leakage-Detection -  This is the Github Repo)

I tried installing the composer and tried to recover the autoload.php but that is not working.

Comment: Did you change all occurrences of `require 'C:Path to Composer Autoload php File';` in the PHP files to match your composer autoload?

Comment: I would not go near that code with a a barge pole. Just because its been left lying around on GitHub does not mean its good code or event that it performs the function it is documented to do

Comment: My answer will install autoload, but after looking through that repo, i think you are better off looking for another repo to clone and build upon.

Comment: That repository looks like a quick backup someone did, and not really something that's designed to be redistributed, and it's most likely not even tested. Where did you find about it?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can see the repository doesn't have a `composer.json`. As stated in the following documentation you can create it yourself, however if this project uses other composer includes you probably won't be able to get it to work.

https://getcomposer.org/doc/01-basic-usage.md#autoloading

Create composer.json then copy and paste this in there, then run `composer install`

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {"Acme\\": "src/"}
    }
}
```